# Get destinations response within mirth custom webservice

Tags: java, web-services, mirth

I've created successfully a custom web service for a source connector, i.e, I can successfully call a method from that custom webservice a pass a message to the destinations of that channel something like this inside the webservice:

```
message="a XML message here";
RawMessage rawMessage = new RawMessage(message);

try {
     messageresult=receiver.processData(rawMessage);
    } catch (Exception e) {
       ...
        }
```

I need to return to webservice client the response of the source connector, which I've configured as to be autogenerated before processing on the source connector interface.

How can I do it?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The result message (not result message status) will appear in the return of the 'processData' method.

If you choose the response to be the postProcessor script in the source settings, and, have a postprocessor like this:

```
var r1=responseMap.get('Destination 1').getStatus();

return r1;
```

You'll get the response status as the response message.

Thanks